# Batch How to treat dynamic FOR /F loop results with unknown amount of returned parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, delimiter

I have a function that works well in xp but fails in windows10 as i cant use the TAB as delimeter, only SPACE

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...
CALL :myfunc VARtoSET KEY VALUE

:myfunc
FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=3 delims=    " %%A IN (`REG QUERY "%~2" /v "%~3"`) DO CALL SET "%~1=%%A"
goto :eof
...
endlocal
```

It returns correctly the data and expands possible variables like (CALL SET)

However if i try to use it on windows 10 ... it fails - seems like w10 doesnt like the literal TAB as i get absolutely no result using a literal TAB. If I remove the delimeter it becomes just a space (not a TAB and or SPACE as i read in some places) But I cannot use space as delimeter as the value or the data may contain a space itself and will ruin the purpose.

Comment: `"... tokens=2,* ..." %%A in ... DO CALL SET "%~1=%%B"`

Comment: `skip` isn't required, because `%~1` will be set from the last line of output anyhow. You can also change the back ticks, **`\``**, to single quotes, **`'`**, and  remove the `usebackq` option too.

Comment: this will work when there is no space in the key value - the skip is perfectly adequate for this purpose

Comment: Remove the `CALL` as it's superflous at best, but it can also bring you nasty side effects

Comment: you mean one can execute the command without it or do you mean in the context of the few lines statet above? without the call in front of it it will just become a label not a function call isnt it?

Comment: Sorry, I mean only the `CALL` in `CALL SET "%~1=%%A"`, that should be `SET "%~1=%%A"` instead

Comment: The default delimiters are `SPACE` and `TAB` so you do not need to use the `DELIMS` option at all. The `DELIMS` option is used to override the defaults. You can adjust your TOKENS option to `TOKENS=2*` and then use `%%B` instead of `%%A`.

Comment: @Squashman As he already said, the key can also contain spaces. But when I tried req query there are only spaces in the output, I didn't see any TABs at all (Win7)

Comment: @jeb you are right: xp*s RQ prints TAB as delimeter W7+ uses SPACE - really havent expected this

Comment: @jeb the `CALL SET` is required to expand variables that may be contained in the string - so its fully intentional and breaks using only `SET`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after dicovering that i wont get any TAB delimeters out of my reg query on w10 (xp does use TAB in output) i decided to solve this as follow

We have a KEY_VALUE with possible whitespace (%3)
We get a KEY_DATA result with possible whitespace (%1)

In order to get the proper offset for out token of interest we count the elements of the KEY_VALUE passed to it, increase counter on elements

```
:myfunc
SET /A tk_offset=1
FOR %%A IN (%~3) DO SET /A tk_offset+=1
```

ignore the first returned parameter (%tk_offset%) that contains the DATA_TYPE and use (*) the rest as %%B

```
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=%tk_offset%,*" %%A IN ('REG QUERY "%~2" /v "%~3"') DO CALL SET "%~1=%%B"
GOTO :eof
```

We assign our result to %1 and expand possible variables using CALL SET

Works on both winxp & win10

Comment: I was just going to suggest something similar but this works better. You essentially expanding on my idea in my comment above. I was thinking you could just assign everything to the variable and then do string replacement to remove %3 from the output.